# Proving a version of Roché's Theorem for curves

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove a version of Roché's theorem (which is sometimes also called the dog on a leash theorem) that makes a statement about the winding numbers of curves that are sufficiently close to each other.

> Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ be any point and $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: [0,1]
> \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_0 \}$ be two closed curves such that for
> any $t \in [0,1]$ we have
>
> $$ |\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)|<|z_0-\gamma_1(t)|. \tag{1} $$
>
> Show that $n_{\gamma_1}(z_0)=n_{\gamma_2}(z_0)$.

Intuitively it is clear that this must be true. Since the graphs of the curves are sufficiently close it is clear that the they must have the same number of revolutions around $z_0$.

My attempt:

Define

$$
H: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}, \ H(t,s)=\gamma_1(t)+s(\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_1(t))
$$

Then $H$ is a homotopy where $H(0,s)=H(1,s)$. Hence we may define a family of closed curves via $\gamma_s(t)=H(t,s)$. The condition (1) implies that $z_0 \notin \gamma_s([0,1])$. So I get the formula

$$
n_{\gamma_s}(z_0)
=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma_s} \frac{1}{z-z_0} dz
=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\gamma'_s(t)}{\gamma_s(t)-z_0} dt. 
$$

Now let $\varepsilon>0$. I want to show that there is $\delta>0$ such that

$$
|n_{\gamma_{s'}}(z_0)-n_{\gamma_s}(z_0)| < \varepsilon \ \text{for all} \ s',s \in [0,1] \ \text{where} \ |s'-s|<\delta.
$$

This will imply that

$$
g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{Z}, \ g(s)=n_{\gamma_s}(z_0)
$$

is a continous function. Since $g$ is integer-valued it follows that it is constant and thus $n_{\gamma_s}(z_0)$ does not depend on $s$, which is what I need to prove the statement. I am however having difficulties to prove the continuity of $g$. I may define $h(s,t)=\frac{\gamma'_s(t)}{\gamma_s(t)-z_0}$ which is a continous function in $t$. Moreover, because $H$ is continous it also follows that $h$ is continous in $s$, too. This implies that $|h|$ attains its maxmimum on the compact set $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Then

$$
|n_{\gamma_{s'}}(z_0)-n_{\gamma_s}(z_0)|
=\left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\right| \left| \int_{0}^{1} h(s',t)-h(s,t) dt \right|
$$$$\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} |h(s',t)-h(s,t)| dt
$$$$\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \ \underset{\substack{s',s \in [0,1] \\ t \in [0,1]}}{\text{max}} \ |h(s',t)-h(s,t)|
$$

But I do not see how to get the needed continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below proof.

Let $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to \Bbb C\backslash \{z_0\}$ be a homotopy between $H(\bullet,0)=\gamma_0$ and $H(\bullet, 1)=\gamma_1$. Now, the function $[0,1]^2\ni (s,t)\longmapsto H(s,t)-z_0\in\Bbb C\backslash\{0\}$ has a continuous logarithm $F$ as $[0,1]^2$ is star-shaped. Now, the function $$[0,1]\ni s\longmapsto\frac{F(1,s)-F(0,s)}{2\pi i}=\text{ind}_{H(\bullet, s)}(z_0)$$ is continuous, integer-valued on the conncted set $[0,1]$, hence a constant.

Comment: Let $f:X\to \Bbb C\backslash\{0\}$ be a continuous function where $X$ is arbitrary topological space. A continuous function $F:X\to \Bbb C$ is said to be continuous logarithm of $f$ if $\exp\circ F=f$.